# JavaScript if statement for radio button check

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple quiz, using a mixture of AJAX and JavaScript.

The idea is that if you click the right radio button, you'll get a 1 added to your score. But just for now, I want to check it's working by showing an `alert` that says CORRECT when you check the correct button.

See here, I've only put the code into QUESTION1.

http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp-assets/quiz/quiz.php

This is how the radio buttons are coded, with an ID only for the correct answer:

```
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="thunderbolt">Thunder Bolt<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="lightningbolt" id="lightningbolt">Lightning Bolt<br>
```

And here is the script that runs. It should dictate that the input with `id="lightning"` = `correctAnswer` - and then is `correctAnswer` is checked, the alert will show. Else it does nothing

```
var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("lightningbolt");

if (correctAnswer.checked){
    alert("CORRECT");
}
else(){}
```

This doesn't seem to work and I see no JS errors, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the open and close parenthesis after the `else` statement causes a syntax error.

```
if (correctAnswer.checked){
    alert("CORRECT");
}else{

}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qxb5Z/

Adding the following in the `head` section should make things work:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("question_1a").onclick = function(){
        var correctAnswer = document.getElementById("lightningbolt");
        if (correctAnswer.checked){
            alert("CORRECT");
        }
     };
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Francesca Did you "adjust" the else statement by removing it, or did you modify it in another way?

Comment: @Francesca Is this code within a function assigned to an eventhandler? Something needs to trigger the execution of this code.

Comment: I am not seeing the alert on the JSFiddle either... I copied your code exactly.

Comment: It is not in an event handler, I thought that the if statement would work as the event handler? Essentially, if the user hits the radio button with the ID assigned to correctAnswer, then they should see an alert (and var quizScore; should have 1 added to it)

Comment: @Francesca The Fiddle is working, did you choose the right answer then hit check answer?  You will notice I assign a function to be executed when the `onclick` eventhandler is fired on the `div`.

Comment: Thanks I see it now, so there needs to be an event for it to trigger e.g bound to a button click.

Comment: Exactly, however if your button submits the form, you may need to prevent the form submission.